# VHDL output module to input in another module

Tags: input, output, vhdl

I am new to VHDL and i am trying to implement CMOS CD4543 into FPGA basys 3 ,
and i am stuck because i wrote 2 modules and the output remains U and this output is supposed to be input in the second module. I've made testbenches for both of them and separatly they are working corect. I will put the code here to see what is wrong. Thanks!

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity latch is

    Port ( datain : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

           load : in STD_LOGIC;
           data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
end latch;

architecture Behavioral of latch is

    signal data : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

Begin

    data <= datain when (load = '1') else data;
    data_out <= data;  
end Behavioral;



library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity to7segments is

    Port ( datain : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

            bl :in std_logic;

            ph :in std_logic;

           seg : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);

           an : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));

end to7segments;

architecture behavioral of to7segments is

    signal data: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

Begin

    an<="1110";

decoder: process(bl,ph)

begin 
     if bl= '0' then

        if ph ='1' then

            data <= not(datain);

            end if;

             data<=datain;

            case data is 
               when "0000" => seg <="0000001" ;

            when "0001" => seg <= "1001111" ;

            when "0010" => seg <= "0010010" ;

            when "0011" => seg <= "0000110" ;

            when "0100" => seg <= "1001100" ;

            when "0101" => seg <= "0100100" ;

            when "0110" => seg <= "0100000" ;

            when "0111" => seg <= "0001111" ;

            when "1000" => seg <= "0000000" ;

            when "1001" => seg <= "0000100" ;

            when "1010" => seg <= "0001000" ;

            when "1011" => seg <= "1100000" ;

            when "1100" => seg <= "0110001" ;

            when "1101" => seg <= "1000010" ;

            when "1110" => seg <= "0110000" ;

            when "1111" => seg <= "0111000" ;

            when others => seg <= "1111111" ;
            end case;
         elsif bl='1' then
             seg<="1111111";   
            end if;
 end process decoder;

end behavioral;


library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity top is

    Port ( load : in STD_LOGIC;

           ph : in STD_LOGIC;

           bl : in STD_LOGIC;

           datain :in std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);

           seg : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);

           an : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));

end top;

architecture behavioral of top is

 component latch PORT ( datain : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

          load : in STD_LOGIC;

          data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));

          end component;

   component to7segments PORT ( datain : inout STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);

                     bl :in std_logic;

                     ph :in std_logic;

                    seg : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0);

                    an : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));

                    end component;

         signal datain2 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin

    latch1:  latch PORT MAP(datain=>datain,

    load =>load,

    data_out=>datain2);

    decoder: to7segments PORT MAP(datain=>datain2,

    bl=>bl,

    ph=>ph,

    seg=>seg,

    an=>an);


end behavioral;
```

Comment: Please format your question. It's unnecessarily hard to read.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Besides your code being hard to read there's at least one show stopper in top. The component declaration for to7segments doesn't match the entity declaration for to7segments, and would be unbound (which would produce a warning). The component declaration in top should have port datain as mode in and not mode inout. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and note that your problem statement isn't specific.

Comment: The first component you declare is a latch. You should not use latches in FPGAs. Instead use registers.